# Assign responseXML values to table cells created by a for loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have been playing with JavaScript and [Arduino Ethernet Shield](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoEthernetShield) for a while and I am trying to send data from Arduino to the webpage it serves using AJAX. The data I send is an array of 24 variables. In order to display the data I created a table in JavaScript using the `for()` loop. The problem is that when I try to assign the variables to the table cells (one variable per cell), only the first cell of the table receives data. The thing is that when I create the table using HTML (all cells created with the `<td></td>` tags), the variables are assigned to the table cells properly. Thank you for your time!

Here is my code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Arduino WebBased Weather Station</title>
            <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
            <style>
                @charset 'UTF-8';@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700);
                body {
                    background-color: black; 
                    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
                    line-height: 1em;
                    text-align: center;
                    Color: #cccccc;
                }
                table {
                    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    width: 100%;
                    margin-left:auto; 
                    margin-right:auto;
                }
                th {
                    border: 1px solid #336699;
                    color:#0040ff;
                    text-align: center;
                    padding: 8px;
                }
                td {
                    border: 1px solid #336699;
                    color:#0080ff;
                    text-align: center;
                    padding: 8px;
                }
                td.td2 {
                    border: 1px solid #336699;
                    color:#0080ff;
                    text-align: left;
                    padding: 8px;
                }
            </style>
            
            <h1>Arduino Web-Based Weather Station</h1><hr>
            <h3>WELCOME!</h3>
            <p>Project is hosted on github. Please visit my <a href='https://github.com/zissis-pap'>page</a> for more!</p><hr>
    
        </head>
        <body onload="BuiltArray(); GetArduinoIO()"><br>
            
            <div id="array1"></div>
            
        <script>
        var bool = false;
        function BuiltArray() {
            var arr1 ="<table style='width:100%'><tr><th colspan='25'>\
            AVERAGE CONDITIONS FOR THE LAST 24 HOURS</th></tr><tr><td\ class='td2'>HOURS:</td>"
            for (var i = 0; i <= 23; i++) {
                arr1 += "<td><font color='#3d0099'>\
                         <span class='hrs'>...</span></font></td>";
            }
            arr1 += "</tr></table>";
            document.getElementById("array1").innerHTML = arr1;
            bool = true;
        }
      function GetArduinoIO() {
                if(bool == true) {
                    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState == 4) {
                            if (this.status == 200) {
                                if (this.responseXML != null) {
                                    // XML file received - contains analog values, switch values and LED states
                                    var count;
                                    // get analog inputs
                                    var num_an = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('hours').length;
                                    for (count = 0; count < num_an; count++) {
                                        document.getElementsByClassName("hrs")[count].innerHTML =
                                            this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('hours')[count].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // send HTTP GET request with LEDs to switch on/off if any
                    request.open("GET", "ajax_inputs", true);
                    request.send();
                    setTimeout('GetArduinoIO()', 2000);
                }
      }
     </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I would suggest caching the result of your `getElementsBy*Name` queries outside of the loop so that it does those queries once, not 24 times. `var hours = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagname('hours');`, then `hours.length` and `hours[count].childNodes[0].nodeValue`. If you add an example of what the XML looks like, it would be easier to help with the rest.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The XML file has the following format:

<?xml version = \"1.0\" ?>
<inputs>
<hours>var1</hours>
<hours>var2</hours>
            ...
<hours>var24</hours>
</inputs>